# Show content inside navigation bar (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I added a navigation bar styled with bootstrap to my page.  When clicking the nav links I'm looking for a way to load below the navbar different templates according to the option selected without changing the URL route and keeping the navbar in his position.  My current issue is that when I click the links the navigation bar disappear and the template is loaded in a single page.

Any advice?

```
<template name="eventContainer">
{{#if currentUser}}
    {{#each eventTag}}
        <nav role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <h5 class="panel-title"> {{title}} </h5>
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/newMatches"> {{eventMatchesCount eventCode}} Peers</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="/members"> {{eventMembersCount eventCode}} Members </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>           
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}         
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I resolve it like that.  All templates inside tabs are loaded when main page is loaded and not when the user surf the tabs, that is not a big issue for me because I have few tabs.

```
<template name="eventContainer">
Event List
<nav>
  <div>
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#newmatches" aria-controls="newmatches" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">New Matches</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#members" aria-controls="members" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Members</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#findevent" aria-controls="findevent" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Find Event</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">{{ > home}}</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="newmatches">{{> newMatches}}</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="members">{{> members}}</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="findevent">{{> findEvent}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</template>
```